# Postman not returning a table

Tags: netbeans, postman, web-deployment

I am working on a web dev project right now using netbeans 8.2 + glassfish 4.1

My code seems to be good since it is not showing any type of errors. However, when I try to run it and I paste the code in google postman my response look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<clubss></clubss>
```

Just to make sure, my project is on football teams. I currently have a table with 3 team only, just to keep it short. A weird thing that I noticed is the last line - "clubss". I searched through my code and could not find the word "clubss" anywhere - I do have loats of "club" + "clubs" but nowhere a "clubss".

However, most important thing to me at the moment is to get the whole thing running and to display the 3 teams in postman.

If you require any code just let me know. I did not paste them in in the first place because
a) it might turned out it is not needed
b) they are fairly long and it would make the post look bad.
However if you do need it I will update it immediately.

Thanks in advance, any help appreciated.    UPDATE

```
      import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
      import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
      import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

      @XmlRootElement(name="clubs")
      // define the field order
      @XmlType(propOrder={"id", "name", "year", "country", "league",  
      "picture", "description"})

       public class Clubs {
       private int id;
       private String name, year, country, league,  picture, description;

// JAXB requires a default ctor
public Clubs(){

}

 public Clubs(int id, String name, String year, String country, String league,  String picture, String description) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.country = country;
    this.year = year;
    this.league = league;
    this.picture = picture;
    this.description = description;
}
@XmlElement
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@XmlElement
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@XmlElement
public String getYear() {
    return year;
}
public void setYear(String year) {
    this.year = year;
}

@XmlElement
public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}
public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

@XmlElement
public String getLeague() {
    return league;
}
public void setLeague(String league) {
    this.league = league;
}


@XmlElement
public String getPicture() {
    return picture;
}
public void setPicture(String picture) {
    this.picture = picture;
}

@XmlElement
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Clubs{" + "id=" + id + ", name=" + name +  ", country=" + country + ", league=" + league + ", year=" + year + ", picture=" + picture + ", description=" + description + '}';
    }
}




package dao;


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ClubsDAO {

private Connection con = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClubsDAO dao = new ClubsDAO();

    int nextId = dao.getNextClubId();
    System.out.println(nextId);
}

public ClubsDAO() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/CD_WD3_DB",
                "sean", "sean");
        System.out.println("OK");

} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        //Logger.getLogger(ClubsDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        //Logger.getLogger(ClubsDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println("SQLException");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public int updateClubs(Clubs clubs){
    int rowsUpdated=0;
 try{
        PreparedStatement ps =  con.prepareStatement(
                "UPDATE APP.CLUB SET NAME=?, YR=?, COUNTRY=?,"
                        + "LEAGUE=?, DESCRIPTION=?, PICTURE=? WHERE "
                        + "ID = ?");
        ps.setString(1, clubs.getName());
        ps.setString(2, clubs.getYear());
        ps.setString(4, clubs.getCountry());
        ps.setString(5, clubs.getLeague());
        ps.setString(6, clubs.getDescription());
        ps.setString(7, clubs.getPicture());
        ps.setInt(8, clubs.getId());
        rowsUpdated = ps.executeUpdate();
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.err.println("Exception in executeUpdate()");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }
    return rowsUpdated;// 1
}
 public int addClubs(Clubs clubs){
   int numRowsInserted=0;
 try{
        PreparedStatement ps =  con.prepareStatement(
                "INSERT INTO APP.CLUB "         // CLUBS??
                +  "(ID, NAME, YR, COUNTRY, "
                            + "LEAGUE, DESCRIPTION, PICTURE) "
                            + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        ps.setString(1, clubs.getName());
        ps.setString(2, clubs.getYear());
        ps.setString(4, clubs.getCountry());
        ps.setString(5, clubs.getLeague());
        ps.setString(6, clubs.getDescription());
        ps.setString(7, clubs.getPicture());
        ps.setInt(8, clubs.getId());

        numRowsInserted = ps.executeUpdate();
    }catch (Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }
    return numRowsInserted;
}
 public int getNextClubId(){
    int nextClubId = -1;

    try{
        PreparedStatement ps =
                con.prepareStatement(
                    "SELECT MAX(ID) AS MAX_ID FROM APP.CLUB");

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        if(!rs.next()){ // set the db cursor
            return -1;
        }

        nextClubId = rs.getInt("MAX_ID") + 1;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }


    return nextClubId;
}

  public List<Clubs> findAll() {
    List<Clubs> list
            = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        PreparedStatement pstmt
                = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM APP.CLUB ORDER BY ID");
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            list.add(processRow(rs));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        //Logger.getLogger(ClubsDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println("SQLException");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return list;
}

  public Clubs processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    Clubs clubs = new Clubs();
    clubs.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
    clubs.setName(rs.getString("name"));

    clubs.setCountry(rs.getString("country"));
    clubs.setLeague(rs.getString("league"));
    clubs.setYear(rs.getString("yr"));
    clubs.setPicture(rs.getString("picture"));
    clubs.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));

    return clubs;
}

   public Clubs findById(int clubId) {
    Clubs club = null;
    try {
        PreparedStatement pstmt
                = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM APP.CLUB WHERE ID=?");
        pstmt.setInt(1, clubId);

        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        if (!rs.next()) {  // !F => T
            return null;
        }

        // we have a record
        club = processRow(rs);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        //Logger.getLogger(ClubDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println("SQLException");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return club;
}
   public List<Clubs> findByName(String name) {
    List<Clubs> list
            = new ArrayList<Clubs>();
    try {
        PreparedStatement pstmt
                = con.prepareStatement(
                        "SELECT * FROM APP.CLUB "
                        + "WHERE UPPER(NAME) "
                        + "LIKE ? ORDER BY NAME");
        pstmt.setString(1, "%" + name.toUpperCase() + "%");
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            list.add(processRow(rs));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;

}

   public int deleteById(int clubId){
    int numRowsDeleted=0;

    try{
        PreparedStatement pstmt =
                con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM APP.CLUB WHERE ID=?");
        pstmt.setInt(1, clubId);

        numRowsDeleted = pstmt.executeUpdate();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return numRowsDeleted; // 0 == failure; 1 == success
}
public int deleteAllClubs(){
    int result=0;

    try{
        PreparedStatement pstmt =
                con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM APP.CLUB");

        result = pstmt.executeUpdate(); // 0 == failure; >=1 == success
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result; // 0 == failure; >=1 == success

    }

}







 package rest.clubs;

// link into JAX-RS

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestConfig extends Application{
@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses(){
    final Set<Class<?>> classes =
            new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    classes.add(ClubsResource.class);
    return classes;
    }
}






    package rest.clubs;

    import dao.Clubs;
    import dao.ClubsDAO;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Set;
    import java.util.TreeSet;
    import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
    import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
    import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    import javax.ws.rs.HEAD;
    import javax.ws.rs.OPTIONS;
    import javax.ws.rs.POST;
    import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.GenericEntity;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

    @Path("/clubs")
    public class ClubsResource {
         // this class responds to ".../rest/clubs"
        private static ClubsDAO dao = new ClubsDAO();

        @Context
        private UriInfo context;

        public ClubsResource() {

        }

        @GET
        @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
        public Response getAllClubs() {
            System.out.println("get all");
            List<Clubs> clubList
                    = dao.findAll();
            GenericEntity<List<Clubs>> entity;
            entity = new GenericEntity<List<Clubs>>(clubList) {
            };

            return Response
                    .status(Response.Status.OK)
                    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                    .entity(entity)
                    .build();
        }

        @POST
        @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
        @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
        public Response addClubs(Clubs newClubs) {
            System.out.println("POST - " + newClubs);

            // the 'id' field in the request entity body is ignored!
            int nextClubId = dao.getNextClubId();
            newClubs.setId(nextClubId);
            System.out.println("POST: nextClubId == " + nextClubId);

            // now, our Clubobject is set up; insert into db
            dao.addClubs(newClubs);

    // now set up the HTTP response as per the HTTP spec
    return Response
            .status(Response.Status.CREATED)
            .header("Location",
                    String.format("%s%s",
                            context.getAbsolutePath().toString(),
                            newClubs.getId()))
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .entity(newClubs)
            .build();
}

@OPTIONS
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response optionsForAllClubs() {
    System.out.println("OPTIONS for all");
    // what is the verb set for this URI?
    // what is the API supported?
    Set<String> api = new TreeSet<>();
    api.add("GET");// get all
    api.add("POST");// add
    api.add("DELETE");// delete all
    api.add("HEAD");// get with no entity body

    return Response
            .noContent()
            .allow(api)
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
            .build();
}

@OPTIONS
@Path("{clubId}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response optionsForOneClub() {
    System.out.println("OPTIONS for one");
    // what is the verb set for this URI?
    // what is the API supported?
    Set<String> api = new TreeSet<>();
    api.add("GET");// get one
    api.add("PUT");// update (or add)
    api.add("DELETE");// delete one
    api.add("HEAD");// get with no entity body

    return Response
            .noContent()
            .allow(api)
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "DELETE, PUT, GET")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
            .build();
}

@PUT
@Path("{clubId}")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response updateOneClub(Clubs updateClub, @PathParam("clubId") int clubId) {
    System.out.println("PUT - " + updateClub);

    if (clubId == updateClub.getId()) {
        // entity body id == id in URI
        if (dao.findById(clubId) == null) {
            // id not in db, create
            dao.addClubs(updateClub);

            // now set up the HTTP response as per the HTTP spec
            return Response
                    .status(Response.Status.CREATED)
                    .header("Location",context.getAbsolutePath().toString())
                    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                    .entity(updateClub)
                    .build();
        } else {
            // id in db, update
            dao.updateClubs(updateClub);
            return Response
                    .status(Response.Status.OK)
                    .entity(updateClub)
                    .build();
        }
    } else {
        // id in xml <> id in URI
        return Response
                .status(Response.Status.CONFLICT)
                .entity("<conflict idInURI='"+clubId+"' idInEntityBody='"+updateClub.getId()+"' />")
                .build();
    }
}



@HEAD
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response headerForAllClubs() {
    System.out.println("HEAD");
    return Response
            .noContent()
            .build();
}

@HEAD
@Path("{clubId}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response headerForOneClub(@PathParam("clubId") String clubId) {
    return Response
            .noContent()
            .build();
}
@DELETE
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response deleteAllClubs() {
    System.out.println("delete all");

    int rowsDeleted = dao.deleteAllClubs();
    if (rowsDeleted > 0) { // success
        // now set up the HTTP response message
        return Response
                .noContent()
                .status(Response.Status.NO_CONTENT)
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .build();
    } else {
        // error
        return Response
                .status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND)
                .entity("<error rowsDeleted='" + rowsDeleted + "' />")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .build();
    }
}

@GET
@Path("{clubId}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response getOneClub(@PathParam("clubId") String clubId) {
    System.out.println("getOneClub::" + clubId);

    Clubs club
            = dao.findById(Integer.parseInt(clubId));

    return Response
            .status(Response.Status.OK)
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .entity(club)
            .build();

}

@GET
@Path("search/{name}") //   /clubs/search/Real
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response getByName(@PathParam("name") String name) {
    System.out.println("getByName: " + name);
    List<Clubs> clubList
            = dao.findByName(name);
    GenericEntity<List<Clubs>> entity;
    entity = new GenericEntity<List<Clubs>>(clubList) {
    };

    return Response
            .status(Response.Status.OK)
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .entity(entity)
            .build();
}

@DELETE
@Path("{clubId}")  // Path Param i.e. /clubs/1
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response deleteOneClub(@PathParam("clubId") String clubId) {
    System.out.println("deleteOneClub(): " + clubId);

    // delete the row from the db where the id={clubId}
    int numRowsDeleted = dao.deleteById(Integer.parseInt(clubId));
    if (numRowsDeleted == 1) {  // success
        return Response
                .noContent()
                .status(Response.Status.NO_CONTENT)
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .build();
    } else {// error
        return Response
                .status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND)
                .entity("<idNotInDB id='" + clubId + "' />")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .build();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: [1] When you say _"I searched through my code"_, do you mean that you looked very carefully with your eyes, or did you use software to search every file in your project for the string _"clubss"_? [2] Perhaps try globally changing every instance of "clubs" in your project to "abcde" and see what happens (since regression would be trivial)?

Comment: When I say I searched through my code I basically mean ctrl+f in the actual classes. In everyone. I did found awful amount of "clubs" or "club" but actual "clubss" gave 0/0. in every class (total of 4).

Comment: OK, but just to be certain perform a search on every single file in your project. In NetBeans: Select your project in the **Projects** pane, then **Edit > Find...** with **Containing Text** = _clubss_, **Scope** = _Selection_ and **File Name Patterns** = _(all files)_.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responding, really appreciate.
Done what You suggested. 
"No matching files were found"

Comment: OK. In that case update your post with the relevant code that generates the response, and don't worry about it looking "bad". Also, were you expecting any data for your three teams in the response between the `<clubss>` tags? If so, then you have (at least) two problems, right?

Comment: Yes, I am using few attributes like id, name, year league and so on. The output on postman should print these out 3x (for 3 teams respectively)